# Is it possible to change checkbox state without causing click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, checkbox

I'm trying to find a way to prevent `input[type='checkbox']` from triggering the `click` event when I change his state with jquery.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `.prop()` on the `checked` attribute, no click event will be triggered:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").click(function() {
  alert('checkbox clicked');
});
$('#mycheckbox').prop('checked', true);
$('#mycheckbox').prop('checked', false);
$('#mycheckbox').prop('checked', true);
$('#mycheckbox').prop('checked', false);
$('#mycheckbox').prop('checked', true);
```

http://jsbin.com/ecIQUle/3/edit

Comment: Seems to work. thank you. Btw What is the different between `prop` to `attr`?

Comment: @dvir—one changes properties, the other attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're trying to do, one of the following may help:

- Returning `false` from an event handler: `<input type=checkbox onclick="return false;"></input>`
- Using jQuery's [preventDefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)
- Using jQuery's [stopPropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

with the last likely being more correct.

Comment: I need those events I just tried to find workaround by checking checkbox but avoid the click event once.